# Can I use a PS4 controller on a PS3?

Tags: ps3, controllers, ps4

I have a PS4, but I am going to my cousin's place and he has a PS3. Will my controller will be compatible with his PS3 console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a DualShock 4 on a PS3.  You can plug it in directly to the USB port by default, but if your PS3 has the correct system firmware, it can be used wirelessly as well.

There are a few features and games that aren't 100% compatible, the instructions for connecting the controller to the console and the compatibiliy list is [in this post](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/ps3-games-discussion/227012-list-ps3-games-compatible-dualshock-4-a.html):

> 1. First, plug the micro usb cable into your PS3.
> 2. Next, plug your Dualshock 4 into the micro usb cable.
> 3. Turn on your PS3, and then hit the  button on your Dualshock 4. Note: make sure your Dualshock 4 is assigned as Controller 1
> 4. You can now navigate the XMB, load games, and use it as a controller for games listed below!
> 5. (additional step if a PS3 controller is required) Lastly, turn on your PS3 controller, and make sure it's assigned as Controller 2. In certain games' menus, you will need to use  on this controller before you can use your Dualshock 4.

For wireless:

> 6. Go to Accessory Settings, then Manage Bluetooth Devices
> 7. Start scanning for device then unplug your DS4
> 8. While the PS3 is scanning, hold down the PS and Share buttons on the DS4 simultaneously until the lightbar on the front of the DS4 is flashing rapidly, indicating it has synced
> 9. Plug your DS4 back in, and select Wireless Controller
> 10. Once your PS3 is done registering the device, you may unplug your DS4 and use it wirelessly!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Eurogamer says you can do it wirelessly ([How to use a DualShock 4 wirelessly with a PS3](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-07-02-how-to-use-a-dualshock-4-wirelessly-with-a-ps3)), but you definitely can do it wired, which is better because it reduces input lag (especially if you have a gold USB).

However, you cannot get to the XMB menu, and it seems to only work with Sony controllers (officially licensed ones don't count), as I have tried different controllers like the Scuf Vantage 2 and it won't work.

You can also use some of your PS3 controllers / peripherals on PS4, which are known as "Legacy Controllers." Hori products, particularly the Fight Stick Mini for PS4, have a setting that can switch between PS4 and PS3.

And a lot of products are either already compatible on PC, or there's drivers that will auto download, or, depending on settings, auto setup on PC (my old gold headset works on it). The DS4, even with the Official Adapter / Dongle, won't work properly without DS4 Windows / Input Mapper.

So basically, yes, it will work. And unlike some people state, it doesn't just navigate the XMB.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. Only allows you to scroll through xmb.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Did you try this yourself, or obtained this answer from a credible website?